# Bootstrap table not showing some filters

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to display this bootstrap table with `data-filter-control`but I still haven't been able to do so. The filters are not working in two ways:

1. The filter does not display all the categories included in that column
2. The filter does not work at all

Could anyone please help me figure this out? Below is the whole script. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-5ae1a0698dcc2402e9712f7d01ed509a57814f994c660df9f7a952f3060705ee.png">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="CodePen">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-aec34940fbc1a6e787974dcd360f2c6b63348d4b1f4e06c77743096d55480f33.ico">
<link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-8f3771b1072e3c38bd662872f6b673a722f4b3ca2421637d5596661b4e2132cc.svg" color="#111">
<title>CodePen - Bootstrap Table - Filter control</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css">


<style>
.container {
    width: 1100px;
    padding: 2em;
}

.bold-blue {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0277BD;
}
</style>

<script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>
<script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>
</head>


<body translate="no">
<div class="container">
<h1>Bootstrap table with filters</h1>





<div id="toolbar">
        <select class="form-control">
                <option value="">Export Basic</option>
                <option value="all">Export All</option>
                <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
        </select>
</div>

<table id="table"
             data-toggle="table"
             data-search="true"
             data-filter-control="true"
             data-show-export="true"
             data-click-to-select="true"
             data-toolbar="#toolbar">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
            <th data-field="Income Assets" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Income Assets</th>
            <th data-field="Employed Full" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Employed Full</th>
            <th data-field="Bachelor" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Bachelor</th>
            <th data-field="High School" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">High School</th>
            <th data-field="English" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">English</th>
            <th data-field="Age" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Age</th>
            <th data-field="HH Member +5" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">HH Member +5</th>
            <th data-field="Health" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Health</th>
            <th data-field="Benefit M1" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Benefit M1</th>
            <th data-field="Cit" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Cit</th>
            <th data-field="Sample Used Benefits" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Sample Used Benefits</th>
            <th data-field="Total Sample" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Total Sample</th>
            <th data-field="Total Weighted Pop." data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Total Weighted Pop.</th>
            <th data-field="Weighted Used Benefits" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Weighted Used Benefits</th>
            <th data-field="Use Rate" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Use Rate</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="1" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>7218</td><td>38725</td><td>273927698.951485</td><td>44936410.729928</td><td>0.164044785912237</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="2" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>YES</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>6902</td><td>37851</td><td>267669426.039534</td><td>42804442.2445731</td><td>0.159915321215098</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="3" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>YES</td><td>6818</td><td>36928</td><td>259231128.693021</td><td>41949287.17618</td><td>0.161821951660196</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="4" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>YES</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>YES</td><td>6638</td><td>36499</td><td>256169883.708981</td><td>40725041.7232831</td><td>0.158976695986435</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="5" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>YES</td><td>*</td><td>*</td><td>5445</td><td>32836</td><td>240442125.749909</td><td>35317041.6922081</td><td>0.146883752512413</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>




<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-9bf952ccbbd13c245169a0a1190323a27ce073a3d304b8c0fdf421ab22794a58.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin/master/tableExport.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js"></script>
<script id="rendered-js">


//exporte les données sélectionnées
var $table = $('#table');
$(function () {
  $('#toolbar').find('select').change(function () {
    $table.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
      exportDataType: $(this).val() });

  });
});

var trBoldBlue = $("table");

$(trBoldBlue).on("click", "tr", function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("bold-blue");
});
//# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: is there any error in your `console`?

Comment: This is what pops up:


Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .Total Weighted Pop.
    at Function.gb.error (jquery.js:1453)
    at gb.tokenize (jquery.js:2070)
    at gb.select (jquery.js:2474)
    at Function.gb [as find] (jquery.js:850)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2690)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery.js:2798)
    at n (jquery.js:76)
    at String.<anonymous> (bootstrap-table-filter-control.js:344)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:374)
    at BootstrapTable.initBody (bootstrap-table-filter-control.js:335)

Comment: So check this error where it comes from, you have syntax error in somewhere that made this problem but not in the code you add in the question

Comment: I removed the column for Total Weighted Pop. which seemed to be the one causing the trouble. Now the console throws no errors and the filters still don't work...

Answer (score 1):

Filters don't work when there is a space in the data-field attribute, like data-field="Income Assets"